# How to insert autoincrement value inside varchar field

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have table users in which id field in varchar(36) datatype. I want to insert into id with primary key and auto-increment

Field structure

```
`id` varchar(36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

Internal `AUTO_INCREMENT` is allowed only for numerical types like INT. If you want to autoincrement some other type you have to create the trigger like that:

```
BEGIN 
  IF NEW.id IS NULL
    THEN SELECT max(id) FROM table INTO @previd;
         SET NEW.id = @previd + 1; -- or how do you want literals to be incremented
  END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

`varchar(36)` means that you want to use GUID() as a primary key. If so, use trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytable_autoincrement 
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  IF NEW.id IS NULL THEN 
    SET NEW.id = UUID();
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have table users in which id field in varchar(36) datatype. I want to insert into id with primary key and auto-increment.

Playing Devil's Advocate here:

*Why?*

Id columns are generally numbers and the auto-increment functionality is only natively supported for numbers.  Why, then, should you insistent on keeping this id field as a *character* data type?